# Child server cannot detect parent server users

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

Good day!

I have two Windows 2012 R2 servers in a Active Directory forest, one as parent with the domain *local.test* and another as a child with the domain *child.local.test*.

The child server has been installed recently and is intended to be used just for one application, which needs access to groups and users from the parent servers. The application seems to be able to read groups set to universal scope, but when trying to read users I receive the error `User doesn't belong to "test" group`

I just started working with Windows Server and I'm confused about these results, how can I make this application be able to read users with their proper group memberships? I've double checked the users properties and I made sure that they are members of the desired groups.

Thank you in advance.